# How to specify an effective uid when accessing Realtime Database with the admin SDK on node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to node.js. I have a created a database with users node. Users node is protected with the following rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
            "$userId":{
        ".read" : "auth.uid === $userId",
          ".write" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To access data under users node from node js, I would need to send the uid in auth token payload. Please help me with an example code to send the payload to firebase via node js.

Comment: What do you mean by "send the uid in the auth token payload"?

Comment: And if you're using the admin SDK on node, all of your access to the database bypasses security rules anyway, so I don't know what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Say for instance, user wants to access the data on click of a button. When the user click the button, how do I handle the authentication part (pass the uid) to allow the user to access his data only based on the rules stated above?

Comment: It happens automatically if the user has already logged in.

Comment: Can you please help me provide more clarity. On the firebase console, under rules section of firebase database, I see the simulator which happens to have an option to send the auth token payload to authenticate users. Can you please help me achieve the same through node js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges):

> On your server, when you initialize the Firebase app, use the
>   databaseAuthVariableOverride option to override the auth object used
>   by your database rules. In this custom auth object, set the uid field
>   to the identifier you used to represent your service in your Security
>   Rules.
>
> ```
> // Initialize the app with a custom auth variable, limiting the server's access
> admin.initializeApp({
>   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
>   databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
>   databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
>     uid: "my-service-worker"
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: Thank you for this. As you said, it worked automatically. thanks again. Can we help me with this question pls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671505/firebase-login-current-user